# How does fluid width work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I notice in the twitter-bootstrap.css the following :

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.914893617021278%;
  *width: 31.861702127659576%;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What is `*width` ?
2. Is it 31.9% of body width or just the width of .row-fluid/ancestral element ? I assume that its w.r.t the width of `row-fluid` because my `body`is **1349px**, `row-fluid` is **1147px** and `span4` is **366px** which comes out to be 31.9% of **1147**.But then this should work too :

HTML:

```
<div id="right" class="span4">
    <div id="high">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#right #high{position:fixed; width:100%;padding-left:10px;}
```

If the second case in Q#2 is correct, then the width of `#high` should be 100% i.e. same as that of #right. But I am getting #right **367px** wide and #high **1349px** wide in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `*width` targets IE7 only
2. Percentage widths are relative to the container that they are in

When you make an item `position:absolute`, then it is relative to the entire document rather than the container it's in, so in this case the `body`.

Comment: Thanks! Mine is `position:fixed` but i guess it goes for that too.

Comment: Oops yes, fixed, not sure why I read absolute, but yes it goes for that too. If it was position:relative it would be different.